# Live events in jQuery 1.7+

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I am trying to use the `on` method for future DOM elements, but for some reason instead of calling events on click, it fires them when the DOM objects are dynamically created.

here's the code that I have.

```
$("#checkbox1").on('click', toggleChecked(this.checked)); //this is included in Ajax call success method


function toggleChecked(status) {
    $(".item").each(function () {
        $(this).prop("checked", status);
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toggleChecked(this.checked)` will right away execute the function and then `on` will get its return value as handler which is undefined.

Wrap it an anonymous function so that it will be called when you `click` on the checkbox.

```
$("#checkbox1").on('click', function(){
   toggleChecked(this.checked)
});
```

If you use `toggelChecked` method directy as `click` handler you can get the `checked` status of the checkbox using `this.checked inside the handler.

Comment: @Victor- Mark it as answer whenever you can.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- By adding parenthesis, you are executing the function, you have to pass a reference to the function to .on()
- You cannot pass parameters like you want to do. But `this` in the event handler will be the clicked DOMElement, so you can get the `checked` property value inside it with `this.checked`

Here's a modified code:

```
$("#checkbox1").on('click', toggleChecked);


function toggleChecked() {
    // "this" here is the clicked element
    var status = this.checked;
    $(".item").each(function () {
        // be careful in .each() 'this' is the currently iterated element
        $(this).prop("checked", status);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the event listener within function literals. Otherwise, the function is directly called.

```
$("#checkbox1").on('click', function() {
    toggleChecked(this.checked);
});
```

The function itself can be written more efficiently:

```
function toggleChecked(status) {
    $(".item").prop("checked", status);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As people have pointed out, you are doing the function wrong (the function has to be an anonymous function or a pointer to a function, or string that points to a function).  But you are also using 'on' method wrong, it is not exactly the same as the 'live' method.  You watch the document (or an area of the document), and have a subselector in that.

```
$(document).on('click', "#checkbox1", function() {
    var status = this.checked;
    $(".item").each(function () {
        $(this).prop("checked", status);
});
```

Note: If all your checkboxes are getting created in the 'checkBoxDiv' your selector can be:

```
$("#checkBoxDiv").on('click', "#checkbox1", ...
```

For more information about how to use 'on' see the comparison in functions in the 'live' [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (about 1/3 of the way down the page).

From the documentation:

> Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is
>   straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all
>   three event attachment methods:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery
1.4.3+ $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); // jQuery 1.7+
```

> The events argument can either be a space-separated list of event type
>   names and optional namespaces, or an event-map of event names strings
>   and handlers. The data argument is optional and can be omitted. For
>   example, the following three method calls are functionally equivalent
>   (but see below for more effective and performant ways to attach
>   delegated event handlers):

```
$("a.offsite").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });                // jQuery 1.3+    
$(document).delegate("a.offsite", "click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });  // jQuery 1.4.3+ 
$(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });        // jQuery 1.7+
```